# How to setup Visual Studio to code correct for in-page text/less style?

Tags: css, visual-studio, less

In the attached image you can see that visual studio shows a green squiggle after the td stating that a colon is missing as if it were css. Is there a way to make it recognize the type="text/less" and act accordingly or not show suggestions at all?

[image: incorrect css suggestion from visual studio]

Comment: You're not asking it to recognize `type="text/css"`. Please [edit] your question to say what you mean...

Comment: Oops. Fixed. Thanks